# Adding PPA error

Tags: ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get add-apt-repository to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156348/how-can-i-get-add-apt-repository-to-work)

I was trying to add the PPA for Ubuntu Tweak.  I got this error.  What does it mean?

```
joe@joe-Leopard-Extreme:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
[sudo] password for joe: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (60, 'server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none')
joe@joe-Leopard-Extreme:~$
```

Comment: > server certificate verification failed Either the certificate is not valid or there is a network issue. Possibly a combination of both like a man in the middle attack. Is the error reproducible e.g. have you tried it a second or third time?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I've added some things to try in the comments on the linked question.